# How can I customize user's current website cursor with my Chrome Extension using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, google-chrome-extension, custom-cursor

**I'm developing this Chrome Extension for Custom Cursors, I have the SVG path that I want to apply to the website's files that the user is using.**

1. What can I write in my JS code that can go through these files and apply that SVG for cursor?
2. How could I link a an SVG path produced in my JS to a CSS file? (since the path is for applicable in HTML and not CSS)
   e.g. This is what I got: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M91.224,45.5h-6.83c-1.09,0-2.116,0.273-3.019,0.748c-0.903-0.476-1.929-0.748- ........`
3. Any permissions required other than "Access to all sites" in the `manifest.json`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I dont understand. Could y0u clarify what applying an SVG path to te websites files means? Thanks.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm currently developing a Chrome Extension that one of its features is to, extract the URL of the website the user is on, URL is stripped to domain name e.g. from (https:// www. stackoverflow.com) to (stackoverflow), then using an API the term is searched for to get the nearest SVG icon and ID of the first result is returned, using that ID, I manage to fetch the SVG path of that icon. The problem is, how can I use that path to customise the cursor of the user on any website?